# Finding midway points along CGPathRef

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math

Given a `CGPathRef` how can you find a point 1/3 of the way along the path?

I'm working on a card game and want to show the players hand with their cards fanned out in an arc. They should be equally spaced depending on how many cards they have.

Thanks

Comment: Its much more complex to find the mid point on any possible CGPathRef, than on a specific CGPathRef that contains only one arc. So reformulate your question to the task that you specifically need. (e.g divide arc in equidistant sections, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use `CGPathRef` for this. Instead, use circle trigonometry to calculate the points that you want to use. [link](http://www.coolmath.com/reference/circles-trigonometry.html)

Comment: ah, thanks! thats much more simple, knew I was overcomplicating this.